# RSelenium - how to open a private window

Tags: r, rselenium

So maybe it's a basic question but I haven't quite found the answer yet. If I want to open a new private window with RSelenium in Firefox how do I go about that?

I can't seem to find the proper option after creating the client.

```
rd <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox", port = 4444L)
ffd <- rd$client
```

I'm assuming I have to add an additional option now but can't seem to find what it is.

Help will be appreciated.

All the best!

Comment: did you find anything? I'm so interested.

Comment: Not really to be honest. Gave up on it :( .